# How to skip column in range setting

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I want to count for columns that have color-referenced.

I managed to count the cells using this:

```
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
  var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim();
  var backGrounds = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();
  var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop().trim();
  var BackGround = activeSht.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
  var countCells = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
    for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
      if ( backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround ){
        countCells = countCells + 1;
       }
  return countCells;
};
```

However, it only successful when my range is either 1 single cell and continuous range: i.e. O5 or O5:X5 .

My question is, what to change if my range is like; O5,R5,U5,X5 (skipping columns P,Q,S,T,V,W in between).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to test for the background colour of certain cells.

One approach is to create an array referencing ONLY the cells to be reviewed. The following answer takes this approach.

---

```
function callBgCount() {
  // create a temporary array for names of cells to review
  var myArray = ["O5","R5","U5","X5"]

  var myColorRef = "#34a853"
  var myCount = countColoredCells(myArray,myColorRef)
  Logger.log("the count = "+myCount)

}

function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {

  var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var countCells = 0;
  // loop through the array of target cells
  for (var i=0;i<countRange.length;i++){
    if (activeSht.getRange(countRange[i]).getBackground() === colorRef){
      countCells++
      Logger.log("i"+i+", cell "+countRange[i]+" matched the background")
    }
    else{
      Logger.log("i"+i+", cell "+countRange[i]+", did NOT match the background")
    }
  }
  return countCells
};
```

---

**SAMPLE DATA**

[image: sample]

**LOG**

[image: log]

Comment: I tried this but bumped with error: Exception: Range not found (line 17).

=countcoloredcells('Sheet1'!O5,'Sheet1'!R5,'Sheet1'!U5,'Sheet1'!X5,D2)

Comment: Ok. To begin, this is not a custom function so you can't use it (as written) as `=countcoloredcells()`; second, what is the value of D2?